# In GLGE, Is it possible specify the face of a mesh that a texture should be mapped to? (WEBGL as well)

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I'm trying to make an environment map which is in the form of a cube that has images mapped onto particular faces to give the illusion of being in the area (sorta like google's street view)

I'm trying to do It in `glge`however, with my limited experience, I only know how to map one texture to a whole mesh (Which is what I'm doing at the moment). If I were to create 6 different textures, would it possible for me to specify the faces that those textures should be loaded to?

Answer (score 1):

You could generate the six faces of the cube as separate objects and use a different texture for each. Alternative is to set different texture coordinates for the different faces of the cube.

If you want ready-to-run code, three.js has a couple of skybox examples. E.g. http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html

Answer (score 0):

You should look at "UV Mapping".  Check [this example](http://www.cubicvr.org/CubicVR.js/RenderTest.html).  Roughly, UVs describe how the polygons are mapped (in x,y) on the texture.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a *cube map* texture — it takes six separate images, and you lookup in it with a direction vector rather than (u,v) coordinates. They are the usual way to do environments. Cube map textures are available in WebGL.